# Is really a new Mersenne prime has been discovered for 2018 year?

Tags: prime-numbers, primality-test

I have read in [this link](//www.mersenne.org/primes/?press=M82589933&fbclid=IwAR3Ji3H2yqK-JrS3NqPAvhyWHvAP4zDi4RNW1q7t4sXFqOTqOGoIDeFSG_w) if it is true that $2^{282589933}-1$ is a new Mersenne prime which was discovered in 07 december 2018 , Really  I want to know how this was tested to be a prime number ?

Comment: [Lucas Lehmer Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test)

Comment: Pretty much every new very large prime we discover is a Mersenne prime, verified the way Dubs mentioned. Of course, RSA encryption needs to make use of less obvious very large primes, not obtainable using any standard method.

Comment: There is a typo in the exponent

Answer (score 4):

I can't post this as a comment due to reputation, but this question is a duplicate of [How to verify large Mersenne Primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2879251/how-to-verify-large-mersenne-primes?rq=1)

As mentioned by Dubs, the process used is called the [*Lucas-Lehmer Primality Test*](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/LucasLehmer.html)

> **Theorem (Lucas-Lehmer Primality)**. Let *p* be an odd prime and define the sequence S = {s$_i$ | $\forall$i $\in$ I$_n$} such that s$_1$ = 4 and s$_n$ = s$_n$$_-$$_1$$^2$ - 1, where I$_n$ denotes the index set. The *p*-th Mersenne number, denoted M$_p$ = 2$^p$-1 , is said to be a *prime* if and only if S(p-1) = 0 mod M$_p$ .

A proof of the theorem is explained in the link above.